# Error "You must compile your model before using it" in case of LSTM and fit_generator in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I create my own class which create a Keras model inside one of its methods.

```
self.model = Sequential()
self.model.add(LSTM(32))
self.model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
self.model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

In other method i try to train this model using python generator as data provider.

```
self.model.fit_generator(my_gen(), steps=10, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

This causes an error:

```
raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

Error does not rises if i change LSTM layer to Dense layer. What am i doing wrong?

Keras version 2.2.0 with Tensorflow 1.8.0 backend.

Comment: why not input_shape argument for first layer(self.model.add(LSTM(32)))?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this Andrey? Because right now I am having literally the exact same issue!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem

Comment: Looks like it's necessary to provide an **input_shape** parameter to LSTM layer, i did it and now it working. Thanks to @Mitiku for advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the first Keras LSTM layer still requires an `input_shape` when using `fit_generator` which seems to be missing in the Keras documentation and results in the "You must compile your model before using it" error.

To solve make sure you have an `input_shape` parameter in your first LSTM layer as shown by the example below:

```
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_dimensions), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```